# JQuery successfully displaying data from JSON but can't get collapsible styling to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json

My aim is to code a page which pulls data from an external file and displays the data in collapsible DIVs. I have successfully used the following three files but can't get each item of data to be displayed in a collapsible DIV.

This code for collapsible DIVs does work, but only in isolation i.e. not when I try to apply this styling to the data extracted from the JSON file:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
```

Ultimately I'm trying to create a page like this, but where people can update an external file and the information gets updated each time someone visits/refreshes the page:

https://mortgages.hsbc.co.uk/jargon

Any ideas? Thanks so much!

**# Index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <title>Load Content from JSON File using jQuery AJAX - Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Load Content from JSON File using jQuery AJAX - Example</h1>
        <div id='update'>This is a div. This will be updated with Contents from JSON file by jQuery AJAX.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**# Script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () { // load json file using jquery ajax
    $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
        var output = '<ul>';
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            output += '<li>' + val.name + '</li>';
        });
        output += '</ul>';
        $('#update').html(output);  // replace all existing content
    });
});
```

## data.json

```
[
    {
        "name"      : "George",
        "gender"    : "male",
        "color"     : "white-mustard",
        "age"       : "5 years"
    },
    {
        "name"      : "Pety",
        "gender"    : "female",
        "color"     : "white-black-mustard",
        "age"       : "3 years"
    },
    {
        "name"      : "Alex",
        "gender"    : "male",
        "color"     : "white-grey-black",
        "age"       : "3 years"
    },
    {
        "name"      : "Rex",
        "gender"    : "male",
        "color"     : "white-mustard",
        "age"       : "2 years"
    }
]
```

Comment: where's the collapsible code/style?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my original question so it shows the collapsible code, which didn't display the firm time I posted the question. I have tried using <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a"> in all kinds of places in the index.html file and/or in the script.js file, including nesting DIVs, but it doesn't work and the JSON data is just displayed as plain text. Changing the <ul> to <h1> and the <li> to <p>, for example, does work, and so does adding some CSS to the DIV - but the collapsible code doesn't work and is the key thing I'm trying to achieve.